# Probablity of sum probablities

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem

I am not expert in probability. And it is a question to me.

Imagine $p_k$ are random numbers with uniform distribution over [0,1]. And each $r_k$ are definite real numbers that we know. I want to know the probability of:

$$\Sigma_{k=1}^N r_k p_k \geq \gamma$$

N is a fixed and finite natural number and gamma is a number that we have decided.
Is there any function for giving such probability?

**PS**. I know it will tend to Normal when N tends to $\infty$ but I need the solution for finite $N$.

Comment: I think you can start from Irwin-Hall distribution. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution

Comment: @the_candyman thank you good start. Does it support weighs?

Comment: @barej - Is $N$ fixed?

Comment: @barej Apparently, weights aren't supported. Anyway, I think that if you look around for some "constructive" derivation of the Irwin-Hall distribution, you may deduce how to do the job with weights.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "uniform distribution"? Uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$?

Comment: Here is a start I tried doing: Suppose the $p_k$ are identically uniformly distributed in $[a, b]$, $N$ and the $r_k$ are fixed. Then we aim to find $$\mathbb{P}\left(\sum r_k p_k \geq \gamma\right)\text{.}$$
Since the $p_k$ are identically uniformly distributed in $[a, b]$, for each $k$, we know that $$f_{p_k}(x) = \dfrac{1}{b-a}\text{, } x \in [b, a]\text{.}$$
Let us start by finding the distribution of $r_k p_k$ for a fixed $k$. Using the method of transformations, for each $k$, set $X_k = r_k p_k$. Then for each $k$,

Comment: $$f_{X_k}(x) = f_{p_k}\left(\dfrac{x}{r_k}\right)\left|\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left[\dfrac{x}{r_k}\right]\right| = \dfrac{1}{r_k(b-a)}\text{, } x \in \left[\min\{r_ka, r_kb\}, \max\{r_ka, r_kb\}\right]\text{,}$$
[notice that $r_k$ can possibly be negative] and we see, furthermore, that we must impose the condition $r_k \neq 0$ for all $k$.

Now we suppose for each $k$ that the $X_k$ are mutually independent. [I'm not sure if this is necessary, but I'm stuck from here.]

Comment: @Clarinetist Yes N is fixed.

Comment: @Math1000 Yes uniform over [0,1]. sorry for ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\displaystyle Y=\Sigma_{k=1}^N r_k p_k$. Assuming independence, and recalling that the characteristic function of $\displaystyle p_k$ is $\displaystyle \phi_k(t)=\frac{e^{it}-1}{it}$, we may write $$\phi_Y(t)=\frac{\prod_{k=1}^N(e^{ir_kt}-1)}{\prod_{k=1}^Nr_k(it)^N}.$$

Now using Gil-Pelaez [inversion recipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29#Inversion_formulas) you can calculate probability of $\displaystyle Y \geq \gamma$.